# ¿Cuál podría ser el criterio de crear más de una respuesta a cualquier pregunta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

Algo que me llamó la atención, confieso que no lo sabía, es que es posible dar más de una respuesta ([ver este caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117537/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-validar-si-una-variable-que-contiene-el-nombre-de-un-fichero-termina)). No sé si ya se ha discutido este tema, al menos no pude encontrar nada en Meta, entonces: **¿En qué situación se justificaría/sería pertinente dar más de una respuesta a una misma pregunta?**

Comment: Pensaba que ya había una pregunta sobre el tema en meta... pero tampoco la encuentro. Quizás fue una conversación en el [chat].

Comment: Normalmente respondo una sola vez (aunque la respuesta incluya varios métodos diferentes), pero yo he respondido varias veces a la misma pregunta an alguna ocasión; creo recordar que fue porque las respuestas eran muy diferentes y/o iban a ocupar mucho espacio por si solas (aunque eso sería un criterio personal).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, es un criterio que me parece razonable, si tenemos más de una respuesta y todas juntas hacen demasiado extenso el contenido, sería practico abrirla en más de una.  Ahora, "hilando muy fino...", ¿Abrir una respuesta en más de una, no nos daría más chances de obtener mayor cantidad de votos que en el caso de una única respuesta?

Comment: Bueno, eso dependerá de si las respuestas son buenas. Si una de ellas no es muy buena, en lugar de conseguir más puntos, puede que acaba restando.

Comment: Hay una conversación interesante en [meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) (en inglés) sobre el tema. Interesante porque se habla a favor y en contra de hacerlo (con los usuarios decantándose más a favor que en contra del tema), y también porque Jeff Atwood (confundador de Stack Overflow y Stack Exchange) escribió una de las respuestas... posicionándose en contra (aunque su repuesta es la que menos puntuación tiene).

Answer (score 7):

> Nota: esta respuesta es mi opinión personal, no representa la opinión de los moderadores o de Stack Overflow como entidad.

En varias ocasiones ([1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24253/250), [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57315/250), [3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3445/250), [4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21177/250)) yo he respondido varias veces a una misma pregunta, aunque no es algo que haga normalmente. Este es el criterio que intento seguir:

Si una respuesta puede responderse de más de una manera y todas las maneras son suficientemente cortas para entrar en una única publicación, normalmente escribiré todo en una única respuesta.

Pero me planteo escribir más de una respuesta si:

- **Las respuestas serían muy largas** y no entrarían en una única respuesta o alguno de los conceptos claves se perdería entre todo el contenido; o
- **Las respuestas usan métodos muy diferentes**. Por ejemplo, si un problema se puede solucionar del lado del servidor y del lado del cliente, pondría dos respuestas una para cada lado; o
- **Poner muchas respuestas juntas podría ser confuso**. Esto realmente es una mezcla de las dos de arriba... y puede ser una señal de que la pregunta no es muy buena (una pregunta que puede contestarse de diferentes modos no es malo; que se pueda responder de mil maneras diferentes, es una señal de que la pregunta es demasiado amplia y necesita concretarse).

---

Cuando **NO** escribiría más de una respuesta (o respuestas directamente):

- **Cuando una es una continuación de otra**. Si he ocupado el espacio de una respuesta y aún no he terminado de responder, eso es una señal clara de que la pregunta es demasiado amplia y que casi se podría escribir un libro sobre el tema.
- **Cuando las dos respuestas van a ser muy parecidas**. Por ejemplo, para hacer un bocadillo de jamón y queso, pondrías queso sobre un pan, jamón sobre el otro pan y luego los juntarías a) poniendo el jamón encima del queso o b) poniendo el queso encima del jamón. Son soluciones diferentes, pero realmente son similares.
- **Cuando la segunda respuesta que voy a añadir ya existe**. Si otro usuario ha puesto una respuesta igual, lo único que se estaría haciendo es duplicar contenido y crear ruido.

---

En resumen, el criterio que intento seguir es el de simplicidad y claridad: mientras más sencilla y menos confusa sea una respuesta, mejor.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro. Tu segundo criterio, me hizo pensar que ocurre cuando respondemos con otra solución, una pregunta que ya tiene respuesta válida por parte de otro usuario. Si mantuviéramos la idea de una sola respuesta/muchas soluciones, y si queremos ser consistentes, deberíamos entonces editar la respuesta inicial y no generar una nueva. Creo que en general en estos casos casi todos armamos una nueva respuesta. ¿Por qué entonces no hacerlo con nuestras propias respuestas cuando éstas son significativamente distintas o requieren una mayor explicación?.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ese es un buen punto a favor de escribir múltiples respuestas. Y la verdad... no tengo respuesta para esa pregunta. Quizás nos centramos sólo en la respuesta que creemos que es mejor, o puede que inconscientemente pensemos que es _hacer trampas_ (por lo que decías de los puntos). A veces somos nuestros peores jueces.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho imagina que una respuesta contiene dos soluciones. Tú dominas del tema y ves que una es correcta y otra incorrecta. ¿Qué haces? ¿No es mejor poder tenerlas separadas, para votar positivamente una y negativamente la otra?

Comment: @fedorqui, si sin dudas tener separadas las respuestas funciona en ese sentido. En mi caso, varias veces presente más de una solución en una misma respuesta (hasta hoy nunca respondí dos veces). En el caso que  separe las dos (o más) respuestas, y una es mala y la otra es buena, le doy a la comunidad la oportunidad de votar negativamente a una y positivamente a la otra. Ahora si las dos son buenas, eventualmente podría recoger más votos que si hubiera escrito una única respuesta, lo cual, creo, por lo conversado hasta ahora, tampoco sería ninguna clase de comportamiento repudiable.

Comment: Tengo otro caso mas valido todavia.. cuando existe un nuevo framework, herramienta del lenguaje, actualizacion que hace que la respuesta anterior sea valida, pero exista otro metodo solo para una tecnologia mas moderna. en ese caso vale la pena tenerla separada para no confundir a los que leen. Esto es muy comun ya en SO eng, donde algunas preguntas son buenas, pero las respuestas van quedando obsoletas...